# mpirun hangs when run across multiple hosts

Tags: ubuntu, openmpi

mpirun perfectly locally, however when I try to run across several machines it hangs without clear error message.

the hosts file is configured correctly and here is the

```
#mpirun -d -v --hostfile hosts -np 2 ./outputfile
[node01:182941] procdir: /tmp/ompi.node01.1002/pid.182941/0/0
[node01:182941] jobdir: /tmp/ompi.node01.1002/pid.182941/0
[node01:182941] top: /tmp/ompi.node01.1002/pid.182941
[node01:182941] top: /tmp/ompi.node01.1002
[node01:182941] tmp: /tmp
[node01:182941] sess_dir_cleanup: job session dir does not exist
[node01:182941] sess_dir_cleanup: top session dir not empty - leaving
[node01:182941] procdir: /tmp/ompi.node01.1002/pid.182941/0/0
[node01:182941] jobdir: /tmp/ompi.node01.1002/pid.182941/0
[node01:182941] top: /tmp/ompi.node01.1002/pid.182941
[node01:182941] top: /tmp/ompi.node01.1002
[node01:182941] tmp: /tmp
```

hosts file :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost

10.0.0.10   node02
```

I checked the nodes and confirmed that the firewall is off

```
#sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain InstanceServices (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

#sudo ufw status

Status: inactive

I checked ssh between machines and password-less ssh is set up correctly

#ssh node02
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1021-oracle aarch64)